# How to transfer image One device to another device using xmpp framework on iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmppframework

I have made one-To-one chat application using xmpp protocol. Now I want to send image and video in my application. I have search many about the file transfer but i didn't find out the solution. I am using below code for Socket connection.

Please help me how can I do this.

My Code is :

```
[TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:@[@"MyserverHost-desktop"]]; 

XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"1254225445@MyserverHost-desktop"];

 TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[[self appDelegate]xmppStream] toJID:jid]; 

[app.turnSocketArray addObject:turnSocket]; 

[turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()]; 
[turnSocket release]; 

- (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket 
{ 

}
- (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender
{

}
```

Every time Connection fail method call..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I am not sending the image directly to xmpp because it takes a lot time.

In my project I message can be string and it can be image and I found there is only one method to send message i.e..

```
[xmppRoom sendMessageWithBody:@"Your msg"];
```

So for sending the image First I am converting it to base64 then uploading it to my server and getting the URL for that image from server. Once we get the URL just pass that URL in Above method.

Problem here I was facing was how to segregate normal messages and URL (Images)

So for sending normal text I am directly sending it above function but for sending URL I am sending the nsdictionary i.e. I am converting nsdictionary to string and sending it in above function

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"type":@"image",
                               @"url":@"Url of your image"};

            NSString *newMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict];

            [appDelegate.xmppRoom sendMessageWithBody:newMessage];
```

For segregating  normal message and Image in -

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{

    messages *msg = [messages new];

     NSDictionary *dictOfMedia = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                                 propertyListWithData:[[[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                 options:kNilOptions
                                 format:NULL
                                 error:NULL];

    if ([dictOfMedia objectForKey:@"type"])
    {
        msg.mediaType = [dictOfMedia objectForKey:@"type"];
        msg.url = [dictOfMedia objectForKey:@"url"];
    }
    else
    {
        msg.msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
    }


}
```

messages is my model class you can use simply use nsstring for testing purpose.

After this just use any open source project for downloading the image or perform lazy loading on your own.

Hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I use other method to transfer media file.

1)Sender upload media file to server and get a url.

2)Sender send JSON like this:{ "type": "Image", "URL": "this is a url for image" }

3)Receiver receive JSON and download image from server.

4)Receiver show image.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...Can you please send your code.